# Division in Matlab is giving values close to zero

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I have the following code to load a bitmap from file, which is a 256x256 pixel gray scale image:

```
a = imread('E:\images\pic1.bmp');
a = double(a(:, :, 1));

figure;
imagesc(abs(a));
colormap(gray);
axis off; 
axis equal;
title('Input image');

rpm1 = exp(i * 2 * pi * rand(256));
theta1 = 2 * pi * rand(256);
Iprime1 = fft2((sqrt(a) .* rpm1));
A = abs(Iprime1);
phi1 = angle(Iprime1);

W = A / 2;
Q = cos(phi1 - theta1);
T = W ./ Q
```

When I inspect output `T` in Matlab it is a matrix containing values in the range of 0.0000 to 0.0009. 
However, when I display `W` and `Q` separately and calculate `T` manually for a single element, it comes out to be a non zero value.

What am I missing?

Comment: `T=W./Q`divides elementwise, i.e. `T(1,1) = W(1,1)/Q(1,1)`, so there where W is zero, T should be zero....

Comment: What is `grt()`? We have no idea what it returns, so no way to really check your problem.

Comment: sorry....grt is gyrator transform....for the sake of generality, it can be substituted with fft2 i.e. 2-D fourier transform..even with fft2 i am getting the same result....    @RobertStettler matrix W has very few zeros.... so there is no question for the entire matrix T to go to zero

Comment: What output are you expecting to see (i.e. the result of your manual calculation)? And more importantly, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Simply, I expect the matrix T to have non zero values because logically matrix W and matrix Q are non zero....... Moreover when  I dispaly the matrix T as an image, it should come out to be gray scale random noise..but it is being displayed as a completely black image owing to the zero values

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, just go step by step through the code and see where the values become either zero or inf or very very high (for the Q matrix entries). The division itself can't cause any problem

Comment: yup, i checked step by step...everything is okay till Q....none of the matrix is zero...but the moment i divide it, zero appears for T

Comment: Yes, but what about the matrix `W` and its parents `A` and `Iprime1` ?

Comment: W is non-zero..values ranging between 0.0314 to 19.6976......A has its values ranging from 39.3952 to 0.0628......Iprime1 is complex with values from -38.6082-7.8351i to 0.0454-0.0434i......These values appear to be spread more or less evenly

Comment: I think, the question is not answerable because we do not know the contents of `a`, for example. Please provide a small self-contained example.